# Why I have this error using ng serve in zsh terminal in vscode inside an angular project

Tags: angular, terminal, zsh

Reading [this](https://dev.to/deepu105/configure-a-beautiful-terminal-on-unix-with-zsh-4mcb) I found that it is possible to use zsh inside VSCode so I configured these inside *settings.json* for my user:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/zsh",
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'SauceCodePro Nerd Font Mono','Source Code Pro'",
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
```

But when I tried to start my Angular app `ng serve`, it shows:

```sh
zsh: command not found: ng
```

So following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324725/getting-command-not-found-working-under-zsh) response that had a similiar issue I added this to the *.zshrc* file:

```sh
if [[ -s '/etc/zsh_command_not_found' ]]; then
  source '/etc/zsh_command_not_found'
fi
```

But now it shows this, and I am not sure that it is the right package to install:

```sh
➜ ng serve

No se ha encontrado la orden «ng», pero se puede instalar con:

sudo apt install ng-common
```

What I can do? Because with bash it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was missing loading *nvm* in the zshrc file.
So I added this to the .zshrc file:

```sh
export NVM_DIR="/home/espe/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Then I thought someone should have faced this before, and [here is an article about how to solve this problem](http://broken-by.me/lazy-load-nvm/). So the previous code became this:

```
# lazyload nvm
# all props goes to http://broken-by.me/lazy-load-nvm/
# grabbed from reddit @ https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/4tg5jg/lazy_load_nvm_for_faster_shell_start/

lazynvm() {
  unset -f nvm node npm npx 2>/dev/null
  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
  [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
  if [ -f "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ]; then
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # This loads nvm bash_completion
  fi
}

nvm() {
  lazynvm 
  nvm $@
}

node() {
  lazynvm
  node $@
}

npm() {
  lazynvm
  npm $@
}

npx() {
  lazynvm
  npx $@
}

# Add every binary that requires nvm, npm or node to run to an array of node globals
NODE_GLOBALS=(`find ~/.nvm/versions/node -maxdepth 3 -type l -wholename '*/bin/*' | xargs -n1 basename | sort | uniq`)

for cmd in "${NODE_GLOBALS[@]}"; do
  eval "${cmd}(){ unset -f ${NODE_GLOBALS} 2>/dev/null; lazynvm; ${cmd} \$@ }"
done
```

Also, thanks to [scttcper](https://github.com/scttcper), for the improved solution.

Source:

- [The article](http://broken-by.me/lazy-load-nvm/)
- [The gist solution](https://gist.github.com/scttcper/92f477894368a9731634034d46567454)